# jquery Inputmask change comma to dot on decimal

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I was using https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask, but old version. It was not working properly on mobile devices I upgraded to latest version. And now I have a problem.
I was using my own function to change comma to dot:

```
$('.change-dot').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 188 || e.keyCode === 110) {
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '.');
            return false;
        }

    });
```

And using inputmask

```
$('.decimal-plus').inputmask('decimal', { allowMinus: false, radixPoint: '.', digits: 3 });
```

It was working great. After update changing comma to dot not working. I need values to be with dot and client want to enter data on numeric keyboard and automatically change comma to dot.
Can you help me somehow?